# Dynamic type cast in select query

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, casting

*I have totally rewritten my question because of inaccurate description of the problem!*

We have to store a lot of different informations about a specific region. For this we need a **flexible data structure** which does not limit the possibilities for the user.

So we've create a **key-value table** for this additional data which is described through a **meta table** which contains the datatype of the value.

We already use this information for queries over our rest api. We then automatically wrap the requested field with into a `cast`.

[image]
*[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/081a8)*

We return this data together with information form other tables as a `JSON` object. We convert the corresponding rows from the **data-table** with `array_agg` and `json_object` into a JSON object:

```
...
CASE
    WHEN count(prop.name) = 0 THEN '{}'::json
    ELSE json_object(array_agg(prop.name), array_agg(prop.value))
END AS data
...
```

This works very well. Now the problem we have is if we store data like a floating point number into this field, we then get returned a string representation of this number:

```
e.g. 5.231 returns as "5.231"
```

Now we would like to **CAST** this number during our select statement into the right data-format so the JSON result would be correctly formatted. We have all the information we need so we tried following:

```
SELECT 
json_object(array_agg(data.name),
            -- here I cast the value into the right datatype! 
            -- results in an error
            array_agg(CAST(value AS datatype))) AS data
FROM data
JOIN (
    SELECT name, datatype
    FROM meta)
AS info
ON info.name = data.name
```

The error message is following:

```
ERROR:  type "datatype" does not exist
LINE 3:    array_agg(CAST(value AS datatype))) AS data
                                   ^
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: type "datatype" does not exist
```

So is it possible to dynamically cast the text of the `data_type` column to a **postgresql type** to return a well-formatted JSON object?

Comment: First, you need `CAST()` not `CASE`, but second this is not possible unless you use dynamic SQL.  A data type and the name of a data type are two different things.

Comment: Thx, that was just a copy-paste mistake. How would you solve this problem? Postprocessing of the data?

Comment: The SELECT's result columns have the same data type for all rows. (Decided at compile time.) I.e you can't have one type for first row, and another type for the second row.

Comment: `data_type` is name of the column, it's type is `text` and `CAST()` construct requires name of the type.

Comment: Ok so I've just edited my question to give more information! Thanks for all answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is, that `json_object` does create an object out of a `string array` for the **keys** and another `string array` for the values. So if you feed your **JSON** objects into this method, it will always return an error.

So the first problem is, that you have to use a **JSON** or **JSONB** column for the values. Or you can convert the values from string to json with `to_json()`.

Now the second problem is that you need to use another method to create your json object because you want to feed it with a `string array` for the keys and a `json-object array` for the values. For this there is a method called `json_object_agg`.

Then your output should be like the one you expected! Here the full query:

```
SELECT 
json_object_agg(data.name, to_json(data.value)) AS data
FROM data
```

Answer (score 4):

First, that's a terrible abuse of SQL, and ought to be avoided in practically all scenarios. If you have a scenario where this is legitimate,  you probably already know your RDBMS so intimately, that you're writing custom indexing plugins, and wouldn't even think of asking this question...

If you tell us what you're actually trying to do, there's about a 99.9% chance we can tell you a better way to do it.

Now with that disclaimer aside:

This is not possible, without using dynamic SQL.  With a sufficiently recent version of PostgreSQL, you can accomplish this with the use of 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE', which you can read about [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html).  It basically boils down to using `EXEC`.

Note, however, that even using this method, the result for every row fetched in the same query **must have the same data type**.  In other words, you can't expect that row 1 will have a data type of `VARCHAR`, and row 2 will have `INT`. That is completely impossible.

Comment: Just to make a note on your last bit. It technically wouldn't be impossible. If he is storing everything as a `VARCHAR` and he stores the columns intended data type with that record, that value could contain any of the following values (or others): `'2015-12-14'`, `'123.50'`, `'314'`, etc... as long as the stored data type is not wrong, it should convert fine. Granted, this is not an ideal approach as you said. Not disagreeing with that part.

Comment: I've updated my question so it's better understandable. Yes you are right, it isn't the best way to use a database, but we currently are sticked to this data model.

The same datatype problem would be solved if I use a JSON object as return value.

Comment: So you're trying to return valid JSON? That's probably a far simpler problem to solve than casting things to an arbitrary data type. What values are stored in your 'datatype' column?

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, at the end I have a view where all the data comes together. And there I have a column with the datatype JSON which contains the aggregated json object. But this object does only have `String` as values atm. So I want to cast these strings into the corresponding datatype.